# MODULEENTRY32 what whould do?

Tags: c, winapi

```
MODULEENTRY32 me32 = {0};
```

what the above code do?
I read about MODULEENTRY32 but isnt look like this(like struct).

the struct:

```
typedef struct tagMODULEENTRY32 {
  DWORD   dwSize;
  DWORD   th32ModuleID;
  DWORD   th32ProcessID;
  DWORD   GlblcntUsage;
  DWORD   ProccntUsage;
  BYTE    *modBaseAddr;
  DWORD   modBaseSize;
  HMODULE hModule;
  TCHAR   szModule[MAX_MODULE_NAME32 + 1];
  TCHAR   szExePath[MAX_PATH];
} MODULEENTRY32, *PMODULEENTRY32;
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The code `MODULEENTRY32 me32 = {0};` will fill the memory allocated to me32 with zeros, so all of the properties are 0/null/"".